# Missing modules on IntelliJ Mac

Tags: jakarta-ee, intellij-idea

Good Day,

I am trying to build a web module using IntelliJ. Unfortunately, according to the tutorial, I am suppose to see something that looks like this when I create a project.
[image: WhatIMustSee]

However, upon selecting and creating the project, all I see is this:

[image]

I can't understand why I can't see any modules at all. I selected the JavaVM.framwork file. However, I don't see any modules. Doing a bit of research, it seems i am missing the Java EE modules. Please help, I have googled this issue like crazy and there is nothing on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run the **Ultimate Edition** and [didn't disable plug-ins](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html) for these facet/module types. [See this page](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html) for the comparison of the editions.

You can verify the edition in the application `About` dialog:

[image: ultimate]

In case you have Community Edition installed, [download and install](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) the Ultimate Edition.

Comment: I can't use the ultimate edition! It's not free and my company won't allow it. Come on..there has to be a way to install Java EE libraries on the community version?!

Comment: Sorry, you can't have Java EE modules in the Community Edition. It's the main difference between the editions and the main selling point of the IDE. Commercial companies need to make money for living.

Comment: I've been in the situation before where "the boss won't pay" - try to convince him/her by talking about the productivity benefits :)

Comment: dammit..now i have to use eclipse..i hate it so much

Comment: @user1436508 Try to convince your manager that you do a better job in IntelliJ. That should be enough. I can't imagine that all other software you are using are all open source. Maybe your company uses MS Office for example. If they can afford to use other commercial licenses then how can it even be considered a no-op to buy a professional IDE for professional developers?

Comment: every software we use here is free..xcode, eclipse, open office..lol. but yeah, thx for the heads up I shall try